# How fast is Length(s)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need to read the length of a string `s` really often in my program. I set the `s` string once so I could memorize its size in a variable (`NoOfChars`) like this:

```
type
  MyClass= class
    Public
     s: string;
     NoOfchars: integer;  
  end;

procedure MyClass.SetS(const MyString: String); 
begin
  s:= MyString;
  NoOfchars := Length(s); // <-- store it once, read it often
end;
```

I think I read somewhere that `Length(s)` is as fast as reading a constant since it only accesses the length of the string stored in the "hidden" field in the front of the string. It makes sense but since we don't have the source code, we can only guess. Maybe there are also other computations involved?

So, should I use `Length(s)` or should I memorize the length in a variable?

Comment: It's fast enough but still more operations for the CPU than loading a variable into its register. Btw if you care about optimizations you should first const string parameters.

Comment: You are right about Const parameters BUT as explained, I set the string once and access it billions of times, so I would not see more than few nano seconds improvements if I change my SetS function. (I will add CONST but this is not the answer I need) :)

Comment: Delphi already [memoizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the length as shown in [David's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23580166/224704). The only performance improvement you could gain is registry storage or a direct lookup instead of an offset based lookup. If you want this to be safely reusable, you would need to store `NoOfChars` as a class/record field and this won't gain either of the above mentioned benefits. However, I'd like to remind you of the golden rule of optimisation: _Don't ruin maintainability of code to optimise something you don't **know** is a bottleneck_.

Comment: @CraigYoung-Actually I wanted to save it as a public field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FWIW you can easily get a feeling for how much faster the variable is over using Length with a simple test. Of course this does not test all the circumstances and eventualities in your production code but you get a rough estimate.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Diagnostics;

var
  sw: TStopwatch;
  s: string;
  len, i, x: Integer;
begin
  s := 'somestring';
  len := Length(s);
  sw := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to MaxInt do
  begin
    x := len;
    if x = 0 then
  end;
  Writeln('using variable: ', sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

  sw := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to MaxInt do
  begin
    x := Length(s);
    if x = 0 then
  end;
    Writeln('using Length(s): ', sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  Readln;
end.
```

In a VM I get numbers like this (release config):

```
using variable: 587
using Length(s): 1255
```

Comment: What really matters is what else is happening. The results here are somewhat meaningless. They would have meaning if the loop did something.

Comment: You read what I wrote above the code, did you? It just measures variable use vs Length call, nothing more. In a real situation it can only get better for the variable version because loading that into the register is always faster than the Length "call".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-You mean that the compiler will remove the "if x= 0" line?

Comment: @Altar No, that line is to prevent the compiler from doing some optimizations since x would not be used.

Comment: My point is that these times are meaningless. Timing is only really relevant in the context of a function that does something useful. I'm sure you agree.

Comment: I am tired arguing with you. The numbers are just to show, yes using variable is faster, period. I am sure some clever people can come up with some special code that will show that using Length is faster but I am really sure that will be some extremely hypothetical code. I also think the overhead of using Length might be negligible in a real situation but as you already wrote only profiling might show that.

Comment: No. `Length` will never be faster.

Comment: You can always optimize `Length` with some ASM. :)

Comment: @user How could it be optimised from its current form?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan SSE, newer compiler etc. ?

Comment: @user You can see what the compiler outputs in the asm in my answer. How can that be improved upon?

Comment: This only tests [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to  a global variable.
You might get even better performance if you use a local variable that gets allocated to the registry.
However, a general purpose implementation would use a class/record field and not see any of these benefits.

Comment: The problem with an artificial benchmark like this is that it seems to advocate the technique because performance improvemment seems to be > 50%.
However, it would cause serious damage to the maintainability of the code.
Also, in a real-world situation this improvement might only turn out to be 0.0001% in a localised routine and even less overall.
Clearly it would be a bad idea to make this kind of change for such a minimal improvement. **However, big cudos for suggesting and demonstraing how it _can be_ benchmarked**.

Answer (score 8):

You do have the source code. It's in the `System` unit.

```
function _UStrLen(const S: UnicodeString): Integer;
begin
  Result := Longint(S);
  if Result <> 0 then                // PStrRec should be used here, but
    Result := PLongint(Result - 4)^; // a private symbol can't be inlined
end;
```

This helper function is marked as inline and indeed the compiler does inline it. This program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  i: Integer;
  s: string;

begin
  i := Length(s);
  Writeln(i);
end.
```

is compiled to the following:

```
....
Project1.dpr.10: i := Length(s);
004060E3 A19CAB4000       mov eax,[$0040ab9c]   // $0040ab9c holds the variable s
004060E8 85C0             test eax,eax          // test for nil
004060EA 7405             jz $004060f1          
004060EC 83E804           sub eax,$04           // offset to length
004060EF 8B00             mov eax,[eax]         // read length into eax
004060F1 8BD8             mov ebx,eax           // compiler optimises i into ebx
....
```

The code is pretty simple. The string variable is checked for being `nil`. If so the answer is zero. Otherwise the length is read from the appropriate offset from the string.

This is certainly a pretty quick function. However, it won't be as quick to call `Length`, even inlined as it is, as it is to read from a local variable. Indeed the compiler may well optimise a local variable into a register.

So if performance matters, reading into a local variable could improve performance. But you must time the real world code to know whether or not the performance difference actually matters.

Personally I tend to store string length in a local variable for reasons of readability if I need to refer to the length more than once. If I know the value is the same every time I call the function, it is clear to express that by storing the value in a local.

Comment: I cannot find the declaration of Length in System (DelphiXE Pro).

Comment: `_DynArrayLength` or `__StringLength` but the compiler inlines the asm.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the length of a string, Delphi reads the hidden length field of the string. But reading that hidden fields needs a few more cpu instructions than reading an Integer. So Length() is fast, but not as fast as reading your NoOfChars field.

In theory the compiler might be able to further optimize reading the length depending on the context. So I'd recommend that you do some speed measurements in the real word application.